# FinancialData Input

Tags: functions, data, finance

What does the function `FinancialData` require as input for natural gas:

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=NGG15.NYM

Is it easier to export the natural gas data to excel, then import into Mathematica? Can a speed up over the FinancialData function be obtained this way? The last two questions are asked under the assumption natural gas is a valid input for the function `FinancialData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
FinancialData["NYM:NGG15"]
```

but most properties aren't available

Comment: @sunspots - To see what properties are available use `DeleteCases[{#,  FinancialData["NYM:NGG15", #]} & /@ FinancialData["Properties"], {_, Missing["NotAvailable"] | _?(! FreeQ[#, FinancialData] &)}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &`